# How can I prevent a DateTime from getting serialized in XML with culture information?

Tags: c#, datetime, dynamics-crm, cultureinfo, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to retrieve my data from CRM. But while doing that, it looks like it is applying culture to datetime field.

I have saved the datetime in CRM as - 01/08/2017 12:00 AM.

But when I retrieve this data with the help from FetchXML, its giving me 31/07/2017 06:30 PM

I have set culture in my global.asax file as -

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
 {
     CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString());
     info.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
 }
```

and web.config file -

```
 <globalization culture="en-GB" />
```

Now when i retrieve the data from CRM -

```
foreach (var item in result2.Entities)
{
    model.SightTestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item["oph_claimreceiveddate"]);
}
```

its giving me this date as - 31/07/2017 06:30 PM

What have i missed here?

Comment: Looks like you're problem isn't so much about culture, but about time zones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common date fields in records that are queried using the `IOrganizationService` interface are returned as UTC `DateTime` values.

You need to convert these values to the proper time zone.